# how to write and read pgm p5 file in java

Tags: java, pgm

I want to read pgm file. I kept image content in byte array. When I accessed pixels, I see that some values are negative. So, I applied "& 0xFF" each byte. I hope it is ok but when I write to file, it isn't same as original image.

How can i read and write pgm p5 file?

```
int i = byteArray[index] & 0xFF; //reading
writer.write((char)(i)); //BufferedWriter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the P5 format is *binary*. You are using a `Writer` and cast the value to `char`. This is good for text, but not for binary data.

Instead, use an `OutputStream` and write the value in `i` directly to the stream.

```
int i = byteArray[index] & 0xFF; // Reading
stream.write(i); // OutputStream
```

---

PS: If you don't feel like implementing the PGM format yourself, I have created an [ImageIO plugin for the NetPBM formats (PNM)](http://haraldk.github.io/TwelveMonkeys/#netpbm-portable-any-map-pnm) you could use. It's open source (BSD license).